# mouseover mouseout keeps executing

Tags: jquery, css

I have a div that is display:none and I want to fade it in when the mouse goes over another div and fade it out when the mouse goes off that div. The problem is once I go over the div keeps fading in and out for about 10 times regardless of whether the mouse stays on or off. Anyone have any ideas?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $(".pic").mouseout(function(){
 $(this).children('#summary').fadeOut(2000);
    }).mouseover(function(){
   $(this).children('#summary').fadeIn(2000);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call .stop() before calling the animation in each handler.

```
$(function(){
  $('.pic').hover(function(){
    $(this).children('#summary')
      .stop(true)
      .fadeOut(2000);
  }),
  function(){
    $(this).children('#summary')
      .stop(true)
      .fadeIn(2000);
  });
})
```

edit: oops, had to fix my copy/paste

Comment: I already tried that then nothing happens.  $(this).children('#latest-comment').stop().fadeIn(2000);

Comment: what parameters are you passing to stop()? if you call stop(true) it will clear the animation queue - if you call stop(true,true) it will clear the queue and finish the animation.

Answer (score 0):

Use a plugin like [hoverIntent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) to throttle the rate of in/out messages.  Usually helps.